# Add condition to Paginate in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

How can i add a condition to paginate in Cakephp3..

This is my code :

```
 $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
        ];
        $proprietes = $this->paginate($this->Proprietes);

        $this->set(compact('proprietes'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['proprietes']);
```

For example Something like this:
`$this->paginate($this->Proprietes)->where(['status'=>'pending']);`

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reading the documentation helps.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html) Read *the whole* page. It even contains example code:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->Articles->find('popular')->where(['author_id' => 1]);
    $this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

Comment: The whole page?! That's a bit extreme.

Comment: @pg.seriously? Did you even look at the page? Most of the page is example code and this specific page is a 1-3 minute read. This is not a lot of text. Programming has A LOT to do with reading and writing documentation. Most of the time people are just to lazy to spend a moment to read but waste the same amount of time to ask on SO.

Comment: Sorry I was just being sarcastic!

Answer (score 6):

From the [Bookmarker tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html) on the official website .

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'conditions' => [
            'Bookmarks.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
             /* for a LIKE clause equivalent use :
             'Bookmarks.title LIKE ' => '%abc%' */
        ]
    ];
    $this->set('bookmarks', $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['bookmarks']);
}
```

the documentation does not say too much about conditions in Pagination. Here is the [link of the official documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#).

Answer (score 0):

### I solved this problem like this. Hope It will be work

```
public function viewProductList()
    {
        $shopProduct = $this->ShopProducts->find()->where(['deleted' => 0])->order(['products_id' => 'DESC']);
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 5,
        );
        $this->set('shopProduct', $this->paginate($shopProduct));

    }
```